# Display multiple image from MySQL database to HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a upload and display image for my website and found this code as a way to do it:

```
$image = $_FILES['image'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($image)){
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($image);
     echo"</pre>";
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_FILES['image']);
 echo "<pre>";
 //this moves the images to a folder
 foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key=>$val){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key],'img/'.$val);
 }
```

(this is just a block of code to save the image array into database)

I already have the submit button in my website and it worked, all of the images I picked moved to the directory 'img/'. Also in my database, I have the column 'images' with data type VARCHAR to keep the images in database, but it is displayed as a text "Array" when I try to display it in my HTML table.

How do I display all of the images that I have uploaded instead of getting the text "Array" in my table?

EDIT:
So to display the image, this is what I did, this is inside my page to show the image ("connect.php" is just a script to connect to database):

```
<table> 
 <thead>
  <tr> Image(s)</tr>
 </thead>

<?php
 include 'connect.php'
 $data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT*FROM my_images;");
 while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{ 
?>

 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $d['image']; ?></td>
 </tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

EDIT 2:
Inside the "$d['image']" is array and I have this inside of it
[What is inside the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEpDt.png)

Comment: how are you displaying it?  can you show your code?

Comment: If you are getting the text "Array", you maybe need to iterate over that array to display the items within that array. Also, how is this question related to MySQL? You haven't shown any database-related code

Comment: I have edited the question, let me know if it helps at all

Comment: Showing us how you save the data in the DB will help figure this out. And if you go to the database directly and look at the `image` field in the `my_images` table, what data do you see in there? Does the data look right or is it just written Array?

Comment: Please share more details. What does `$d['image']` contain? Can you dump it?

Comment: I edited the question again. This time I put an image that shows whats inside the array. @slashroot: it just says "Array"

Comment: @alviratulaha So the content of the image you just added, that is the result of `$d['image']` ? If thats the case then `echo $d['image']` wont work. You'll need to `echo $d['image']['name']` to view the name. Or you can `print_r($d['image']);` to get the whole array printed. Still not sure how your saving the data in your DB. Clearly its not just the filename your saving.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "");
   $qry= "SELECT * FROM tblname where `id` = '".$id1."'";
  $result= mysql_query($qry,$con);

  while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{       
 echo '<img src="'.$rows['image'].'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. Rather, edit your existing answer to contain all relevant information

Comment: Please do not recommend the usage of non-working code. `mysql_*` has been removed from PHP years ago. Also, the given code is highly vulnerable for SQL injection